# Adding ATL Simple Object to MFC project

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2019, atl

I created a new MFC project and tried to add ATL Simple Object. VS give an error "the project need to add ATL support"
So I tried:

1 - add ATL Support, as it is, and got "framework already exists", because there is one framework.h in the MFC project;

2 - Add ATL Support with the name framework2. I copied the content of framework2.h to framework.h;

3 - I create a new MFC project, changed the name of framework.h to framework2.h and added ATL Support has framework. Then copied the content of original framework to the new.

No meter what, keep receiving "the project need to add ATL support" message when I try to add ATL Simple Object. Do I need to do something else to add ATL support?

I already create a COM port using an ATL project, but I need to make it using a MFC project to give support to an old MFC program.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community. Already checked the installed packages and didn't find any missing.

[installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCqJq.png)

Comment: AFAIK, all this ATL wizard is completely broken with newest Visual Studio versions. I mean, it doesn't even work on simple dlls. You should report that to Microsoft, or just manually adds the atl header you need, this should work (but you can't use wizard).

Comment: Thanks by the feedback. What I think is estrange is that in the ATL project the wizard was working just fine, I made the COM server and called him from my client. The only problem was in the MFC project.

Comment: My finding is it works but only in an ATL project (not MFC lib, not MFC exe, not console, not dll)